# If a black hole is made by a hypothetical particle above Planck mass and it has angular momentum will it be a ring Kerr black hole?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, angular-momentum, elementary-particles, kerr-metric

If a single subatomic hypothetical fundamental particle incapable of decay (such as an electron) with a mass exceeding Planck mass possessed angular momentum and it collapsed into a black hole, would it be a Kerr ring black hole?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does quantum spin contribute to the angular momentum of a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/341353/)

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to think about this is with the definition of the inner and outer horizons of a black hole
$$
r_{\pm}~=~m~\pm~\sqrt{m^2~-~a^2},
$$
where we consider the angular momentum parameter at maximum and $a~=~J/Mc$. The mass parameter $m^2~=~GM/c^2$. We now look at this in $n$ units of Planck mass $M_p~=~\hbar c/G$ so that
$$
r_{\pm}~=~nM_p~\pm~\sqrt{\frac{n^2G^2M_p^2}{c^4}~-~\frac{J^2}{n^2M_p^2c^2}}.
$$
The angular momentum is discrete in integer units $J~=~n'\hbar$ for $n'$ and $n$ independent. The term in the radical must be greater than one so we have the condition that the number of units of angular momentum $n'$ for a black hole with $n$ Planck units of mass is
$$
n'~<~\frac{n^2GM_p^2}{\hbar c}~=~n^2.
$$
This is the remarkably simple result that $n'~<~n^2$. This is a Regge trajectory result, and it puts an upper bound on the angular momentum of an $n$ Planck mass black hole.

We can modify this for $n'~\rightarrow~n'/2$ to account for fermions. This means a single sub-extremal Planck mass black hole has two possible states with the $m_z~=~\pm 1/2$. The case $n' = 2$ is the extremal case.